# Calculate a sum of cumulative product over a window frame

Tags: sql, vertica

I want to estimate how my seasonal forecasts differ from real data. I have the following dataset:

```
day         real_revenue    historical_coeff
01/01/2017  100             1.1
01/02/2017  105             0.98
01/03/2017  109             1.05
01/04/2017  107             1.07
01/05/2017  90              1
01/06/2017  120             0.95
01/07/2017  98              0.99
```

On day `01/01/2017` `revenue = 100` and seasonal forecast takes the day over day coefficients and apply it to current revenue. So it forecasts that on `01/02/2017` revenue will be `100*1.1 = 110`, on 01/03/2017 it's `110*0.98 = 107.8` and so on. Then, the forecasted remaining revenue will be the sum of all forecasts for taken day. For example, for `01/01/2017` after applying day over day coefficients the sum will be `688.274235`.

For the second day `01/02/2017` we start with value `105`. So we forecast that on `01/03/2017` we will have `105*0.98 = 102.9`, then, for `01/04/2017` we will forecast `102.9*1.05 = 108.045`, and so on. The total forecasted remaining revenue will be `531.2557215`.

At the end I want to receive a table like this:

```
day         forecasted_total_remaining_revenue
01/01/2017  688.274235
01/02/2017  531.2557
01/03/2017  ...
01/04/2017  ...
01/05/2017  ...
01/06/2017  ...
01/07/2017  ...
```

Essentially, I need sum of cumulative product for each day, i.e. `a + a*b + a*b*c + a*b*c*d + ...`.

Is it possible to write a query like this in vertica or sql in general?

Comment: shouldn't the result for `01/01/2017` be `802.18129365` per the logic explained?

Comment: You can get 802 if you include the last coefficient as well. In my case I described when there are only 7 days and therefore the last coefficient is not used.

Comment: what do you mean by "when there are only 7 days"? the question doesn't mention this.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not unclear. When we start from 01/01/2017 and forecast to 01/07/2017 we will have 121.1133*0.95 = 115.057635. If we continue to forecast to 01/08/2017 then we will have 115.057635*0.99 = 113.9070587. But in this example, I used days up to 01/07/2017, that's why the last value is not included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ln()` and `exp()` to get the product of the remaining values:

```
select t.*,
       exp(sum(ln(historical_coeff)) over (order by day desc)) as factor
from t;
```

Of course, the expression is more complicated if `historical_coeff` is every negative or zero.

Then, you can take the cumulative sum of this to get the overall factor needed for the sum:

```
select t.*
       real_revenue * sum(factor) over (order by day desc) * forecasted_total_remaining_revenue
from (select t.*,
             real_revenue * exp(sum(ln(historical_coeff)) over (order by day desc)) as forecasted_total_remaining_revenue
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: You must add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` because the default `RANGE` will return a wrong answer when there are consecutive rows with the same `historical_coeff` (and is way less efficient).

Comment: Gordon.. i don't think this will give the desired sum of cumulative product. for eg. you add `1.1*0.98*1.05*1.07*1*0.95*0.99` for date (01/01/2017) and `0.98*1.05*1.07*1*0.95*0.99` for 02/01/2017 and so on cumulatively..but the required sum is `1.1+1.1*0.98+1.1*0.98*1.05+1.1*0.98*1.05*1.07+1.1*0.98*1.05*1.07*1+1.1*0.98*1.05*1.07*1*0.95+1.1*0.98*1.05*1.07*1*0.95*0.99`

Comment: for date `01/01/2017`.

Answer (score 0):

In regular SQL (syntax shown here is SQL Sever), this can be done with a recursive cte (provided the DBMS supports them).

```
with rownums as (select t.*,row_number() over(order by dt) as rn from tbl t)
,cte as (select rn,dt,real_revenue,historical_coeff,cast(real_revenue*historical_coeff as decimal(38,10)) as res 
         from rownums
         where rn=1
         union all
         select t.rn,t.dt,t.real_revenue,t.historical_coeff,cast(c.res*t.historical_coeff as decimal(38,10))
         from rownums t
         join cte c on t.rn=c.rn+1
        )
select dt,sum(res) over(order by dt desc) as forecasted_remaining_revenue
from cte
```

The logic for excluding last coefficient isn't clear. This sums up all the cumulative products from a given date until the last date.

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/IJAHW32494)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this (you might want to adjust the number of days in the interval):

```
SELECT
    day,
    SUM ( frev ) OVER ( ORDER BY day
        RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '5 DAYS' FOLLOWING
    ) AS forecasted_total_remaining_revenue
FROM (
    SELECT
        day, 
        real_revenue * 
            EXP( SUM ( LN(historical_coeff)) OVER(
                ORDER BY day
                RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '5 DAYS' FOLLOWING
                )
           ) AS frev
   FROM 
       public.t1
) a 
;
```